# Paypal credentials to apple review team

Tags: ios, paypal, appstore-approval

I have integrated paypal sdk  in my application. The app get rejected from apple review team. They want information about account information, including passwords, in the Review Notes section of iTunes Connect App Information.  Should i provide my paypal account details in Review Notes? Secondly if they use my paypal account to test , amount will be deducted from my paypal.

Comment: No there is option in paypal to create test account for test purchase.

Comment: Provide only what a user would need to use the app.

Comment: @hemant test credentials are used for only sandbox mode, should it work with production environment?

Comment: Stop adding the `iPhone` tag. Your question has nothing to do with an actual iPhone.

Comment: i haven't tried it but i think it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to, create a PayPal account for Apple to test with. You can deposit some minimal amount if need be. Once your app is approved, change the password.

Since the amount will be deposited in your merchant account, you wouldn't really loose the money. (You can also log in to your merchant account and refund the transaction if need be.)

NOTE: Do NOT give out your merchant account info; The transaction will fail if buyer == seller, and you really don't want to give anyone else access to your core business account anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion.